# Does d3.js support customised html for rendering nodes?

Tags: d3.js

I am planing use d3.js to display a network diagram. But while going through the documentation  I am feeling we cannot customise the nodes using custom html template as it is SVG.  am I correct?.  But still my question is   [d3.js](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki) tells D3 helps you bring data to life using HTML, SVG and CSS, means  html also used for rendering the networks. So can I use my custom html for nodes if it uses html to render?

Answer (score 1):

Because I needed a network diagram that required some multiline text, it was much easier (and more supported by browsers) to use absolute-positioned DIV elements for the nodes, and then use a background SVG layer to draw the edges between them.

I haven't had a lot of luck getting foreign object to work properly across all browsers.

Comment: I can't share the code I used, but it's basic. DIV and SVG containers as siblings with the same scale / coordinates. SVG is added first so it becomes the background, DIV has a transparent background. D3 can add child DIV elements with position:absolute for the nodes, and you use the same x/y coords for the edges (line or path) in SVG container. Just use D3 to keep them synchronized while drawing the layout.

Answer (score 0):

D3 does not constrain your rendering technology at all. You can certainly use SVG, HTML, or both. I'm not sure how you're planning to create your network diagram, but presumably it will be using SVG at the overall diagram level. (I can't think of a decent way to show connections in pure HTML.) If that is the case, you'll have to embed HTML within the overall SVG. That's possible, see [here](http://ajaxian.com/archives/foreignobject-hey-youve-got-html-in-my-svg), and D3 fully supports it.

Comment: the foreign object is not rendered here can you give some othere example?